# RecyclerVIew items overlaps after each network call

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a simple implementation of `RecyclerView` with an adapter inside the `onResponse` method of network call. How can I remove all previous `RecyclerView` items or refresh `RecyclerView`?

I have used `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` and `recyclerView.invalidate();` but none of them worked.

Comment: Did you clear the data list before adding new items?

Comment: Reser the data list once the next set of data comes through the onRespose callback and then call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

Answer (score 0):

Create a new instance of your adapter and then call `recyclerview.setAdapter(newAdapter);`

This will remove your old adapter and set the new adapter with the updated items.

If you just want to update the items in the current adapter then create a method inside your adapter to do so:

```
public void addItems(ArrayList<EventObject> eventList) {
    this.eventList.addAll(eventList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And then call `adapter.addItems(moreItems);`

Comment: Won't it simply be more efficient to just reset the data source and call notifyDataSetChanged() instead of creating a new instance of the object?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you use a different approach

1. use asynchronous method
2. use variable which array of object, save data you get from network call in that variable
3. each you call a new request, clear the variable, add data from network call in that variable and refresh the recyclerView

Answer (score 0):

Create your adapter once, outside your `OnResponse` method. Inside your adapter, have a method for setting the items like:

```
public void setItems(ArrayList<MyObject> items){
    this.items = items;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Then in your `onResponse` method you can call `adapter.setItems(items);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear your list before calling notifyDataSetChanged().

Use the following line of code

```
adapter.clearData();
```

Don't forget to add this method

```
public void clearData() {
    int size = this.myList.size();
    this.myList.clear();
    this.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Steps will help you

- After successfully receive response, clear your data set using .clear() method.
- Add Newly received data to the model.
- Notify the adapter.

Suggestion-

- Don't instantiate your adapter, each time after receiving the data.
- Use a public method inside your adapter to do this operation also adding the data.